# how to use jpaReposotory methods with an exist database?

Tags: spring, jpa

who can help me to understand this scenario please. let say there is a client who have been using php as Backend, now he wants to merge his project from php to Spring knowing that he already has a full data and completly defined (mapping, primary key, tables), he export his data as sql (database.sql) so my question is how can we work and interact with this data in Spring Data ?

Answer (score 0):

So you have the database export file(s), you create a new empty database and import those files there, configure your Spring Data to connect to the new db and stop using the Php app if you can (if you continue to use it you will have to somehow synchronize the two databases, more complicated)

Comment: but what i notice, Spring data interface can only work if it has Entity, but we don't want to create Entity because we have already Database as sql.
as example, in order to get list of customer, we are giving Customer Entity as parameter 
 public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {

 

List<Customer > findByCustomer(Customer customer);
}

is this mean we need to create entities again even while we are having already Db.sql